# Lcd screen prints weird symbols instead of numbers

Tags: arduino, serial-port, raspberry-pi

I am trying to make a alarm clock with the raspberry pi and an arduino. I have been having this problem that when i use serial communication to send a number it, the lcd doesnt print the number. I know that the arduino is getting the number, for some reason it just wont print it. It instead prints weird symbols and lines. [This article shows how i use serial communication between them](http://www.doctormonk.com/2012/04/raspberry-pi-and-arduino.html)This is my arduino code.

```c
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>


const int ledPin = 13;
LiquidCrystal lcd(12,11,5,4,3,2);
void setup()
{
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("crystralball");
}

void loop()
{

  if (Serial.available())
  {
     flash(Serial.read() - '0');
  }
  delay(1000);
}

void flash(int n)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.write(n);
    Serial.print(n);
    Serial.flush();
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    delay(100);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi try to change your code in loop like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print(String(n));
    Serial.print(n);
    Serial.flush();
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    delay(100);
}
```

You have to use the method print and passing a string.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Could you explain to me why it worked though?

Comment: because the arduino ide is a little weird.. I'm joking, but you have to cast your int value as string before to write on lcd. And the right method to write on lcd is print(), as required by the library.